# How to substring a MySQL table column

Tags: mysql, database

I want to select a field from table and substring it.

For example:

```
VAN1031 --> 1031
```

I tried this, but is improper syntax:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(R.regnumber,3,3) from registration R
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Of course! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring - ps, it would be `SELECT SUBSTRING('VAN1031', 4, 4)` - start at the 4th character and take 4 characters from the string ;-)

Comment: `select "penguins", substr("penguins", 1, 3)`  prints: `penguins    pen`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You don't need the third argument (length) if you want to select all the characters to the right of a specific index:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(R.regnumber, 4)
FROM registration AS R
```

I also changed the start index to 4 because in SQL strings are 1-indexed and not 0-indexed as they are in many popular programming languages.

Comment: I don't know why `substr(col, 4)` does not work for me, and I have to use it like this: `substr(col, 1, 4)`. why? My problem is related to the MySQL version?

Comment: WHY is this not 0 indexed?  You would think this wasn't built by computer scientists

Comment: @CommandZ WARNING! This is not just a joke! If you use a 0 start index SUBSTR will return an empty string!

Answer (score 35):

You can use:

```
SUBSTR(string,position)
SUBSTR(string,position,length)
SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, delimiter, count)
```

Examples:

```
command                                      prints
-------------------------------------------  -----------
select substr("abcd", 1, 1)                  #a
select substr("abcd", 1, 2)                  #ab
select substr("abcd", 2, 1)                  #b
select substr("abcd", 2, 2)                  #bc
select substr("abcd", -2, 1)                 #c
select substr("abcd", -2, 2)                 #cd

select substring_index('ababab', 'b', 1);    #a
select substring_index('ababab', 'b', 2);    #aba
select substring_index('ababab', 'b', 3);    #ababa
select substring_index('ababab', 'b', -1);   #
select substring_index('ababab', 'b', -2);   #ab
select substring_index('ababab', 'b', -3);   #abab

select substr("abcd", 2)                     #bcd
select substr("abcd", 3)                     #cd
select substr("abcd", 4)                     #d
select substr("abcd", -2)                    #cd
select substr("abcd", -3)                    #bcd
select substr("abcd", -4)                    #abcd
```

From [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

Comment: In your examples `ababab` should be replaced with `abcdef` as the output is confusing because of repeating `ab` text.

Comment: For future reference, the examples are `ababab` because of what they are demonstrating. `substring_index` returns a substring up to a certain number of occurances of a delimiter. In this case, `b` is being used as the delimiter. If `abcdef` was used, the result of those examples would be very different.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
select substring(col1, 4)
from table1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbca0/2). So your query would be:

```
SELECT substring(R.regnumber,4) 
from registration R
```

Of if you want to specify the number of characters to return:

```
select substring(col1, 4, 4)
from table1
```

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that mysql index starts from 1 instead of zero as many programming languages did.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(R.regNumber,1,3) FROM registration AS R
```

Returns VAN and

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(R.regNumber,4) FROM registration AS R
```

Returns the remaining part of the string as 1031

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT substring(R.regnumber FROM 4) FROM registration AS R;
```

and if you want to take the part as an integer not a string you can write:

```
SELECT CAST(substring(R.regnumber FROM 4) AS UNSIGNED) FROM registration as R;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to catch the column without some last characters. For example, I have:

```
This is a string
```

Let's say that for some reason I want column without last 6 characters:

```
This is a
```

We can do (using @bluefeet 's answer and LENGHT):

```
select substring(col1, 1,LENGTH(col1)-7)
from table1
```

It was only an example, but you got the idea, I'm using to fix a wrong database import.