# MySQL Search strings

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to get a row from a tabla which have a column data type of string. This column could have values as follows:

```
 1. "1,2,3,4,5"
 2. "X,3,4,5,8"
 3. "X,X,3,4,5"
 4. "1,2,3,4,X"
 5. "1,3,4,X,X"
```

and so on, ...

I want to accomplish a search for a String like

```
"1,2,3,4,5"
```

I tried with a

```
SELECT * 
FROM *table_name* 
WHERE *column* LIKE '%1,2,3,4,5%';
```

hoping this query could retrieve at least three results (in the example, first, third and forth strings) but it returns only the first string, because of course it's the only string that matches with the specified criteria. Anyone knows a way for me to accomplish this achievement?

Comment: You should look into the `SET` datatype: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html

Comment: Please read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771311/how-to-substring-a-mysql-table-column)

Comment: Which rows would you actually want returned here?  Note that you probably should not be storing information in CSV format.

Comment: In my case, I would like to return any string that matches any part in order, i.e. if soterd string i's like X,2,3,4,5 that would be a match for the criteria I'm working on. In listed examples the first, third and forth strings matches with the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `X` listed is literally the X character - if so, try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '1,2,3,4,5' REGEXP REPLACE(column, 'X', '.')
```

Comment: It's correct, the 'X' it's literally a character that belongs to the string itself. I don't know what's the meaning of this REGEX REPLACE(column, X', '.') but it return 0 results (not even the default string). I will start from here and see what I can get .... Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: MySQL has a regular expression version of like named `REGEXP`. It also has a string replacement function named `REPLACE`. What should happen is replacing the X with . converts the column to a Regular Expression that matches any digit in place of the X.